# ¿Cómo puedo lograr que la fuente tipográfica salga con menor grosor?

Tags: css

Al insertar una fuente tipográfica, no sé cómo hacer para que su grosor/peso pasé a fino

Comment: Simplemente agrega tu codigo CSS con respecto a tu modificacion y te ayudaremos.

Comment: ya intentaste cambiarle el peso?

Answer (score 0):

Hola Diana puedes consultar la documentacón

> [`Font-weight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight)

Sería algo así

```
    /* Poner texto del párrafo en negrita. */
p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Poner texto del div a dos pasos más oscuro que lo
   normal pero menos que una negrita estándar. */
div {
 font-weight: 600;
}
```